# What is the " > " used for in CSS?

Tags: html, css

For Example:

```
html > body {
   border: none
   background-color: #000;
   color: #FFF;
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
}
```

I am not sure if I used the " > " correctly. Anyways, I don't know exactly what it is used for. Is it used like " , " or is it something else?

Is it the same thing as this?

```
html, body {
   border: none
   background-color: #000;
   color: #FFF;
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means direct descendant in the DOM

Comment: So like if there is a div and then a nav inside, you could use " div > nav "? Then it would select the nav tag inside of the div?

Comment: As Matt says it means "direct descendant" thus "html, body" it is not the same than "html > body". First one means "html & body tags", and second stands for "body tags at first nesting level inside a html tag". Inspite of that it's a complete nonsense use two body tags. So in practical terms both rules match the same.